# About PHP memory usage

Tags: php, mongodb, memory

***Environment 1:*** php5.6 nginx1.8 Yii2.0 Mongodb
2Core CPU, 4G Memory
PHP process read 50,000 records from mongodb, the memory usage is about 3.2G.

***Environment 2:*** php5.6 nginx1.8 Yii2.0 Mongodb
4Core CPU, 8G Memory
PHP process read 50,000 records from mongodb, the memory usage is about 1.6G.

It's very strange, why the environment2 memory is less than environment1 when php-fpm process read the same count of data?

Comment: Operating System is the same? Any of the installation has a cache active? And where/how do you read the memory usage?

Comment: OS architecture and FPM configuration is the same?

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit PHP?

Comment: Same operating system! all the environment configuration is the same, just change the memory and CPU. I used the "top" command to see the active process status.

Comment: @MarkBaker 64-bit PHP

Comment: @kmlnvm Yes, I use the Cloud Server with the same configuration.

Comment: @Don can you show phpinfo() from both envs?

Comment: Is it the total memory usage in the system or memory usage just of php scripts? and if mongo operates on the same server like php scripts.